# Collision Detection working half the time

Tags: android, collision-detection

I am trying to check collisions between two arrays, one of moving rectangles and the other of stationery boundaries (trying to get the rectangles to bounce off the walls).

The problem is that I wrote a nested for loop that seems to work for 2 out of 4 boundaries.  Is my loop not reaching all possible combinations?

Here is my loop:

```
for(int n=0;n<_f;n++){
   for(int m=0;m<_b;m++){
       if(farr[n].inter(barr[m]))
           farr[n].setD();
   }
}
```

_f counts the moving rectangles (starts at 0 and increases after each one is added) and _b counts the boundaries.  The inter() is a method I am using to detect collisions and it has worked in all other parts of my program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advace!!!

```
public boolean inter(Rect rect){
    if(Rect.intersects(rect, rec))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The setD() method:

```
public void setD(){
    if(_d==0)
        _d=2;
    if(_d==1)
        _d=3;
    if(_d==2)
        _d=0;
    if(_d==3)
        _d=1;
    }
```

The move method where _d is used:

```
public void moveF(){
    if(_d==0){_l+=_s;_r+=_s;}
    if(_d==1){_t+=_s;_b+=_s;}
    if(_d==2){_l-=_s;_r-=_s;}
    if(_d==3){_t-=_s;_b-=_s;}
}
```

_l is left side, _t is top, _r is right, and _b is bottom, and _s is how many pixels it moves per iteration(set to 1 in all cases)

Comment: Any chance your objects are penetrating the walls in between evaluations?

Comment: I don't think so, I am testing them at slow speeds and there are probably at least 10 iterations before it passes through the wall

Comment: Is another thread modifying the arrays while you are looping?

Comment: Which two boundaries does it work for?  Ones in the same axis perchance?  Or maybe ones not passing through the origin?  If you cut down to one object, do you still see the problem?  If so you could start it near the problem wall, and press a key to activate each timestep, while watching log output

Comment: The method that executes the loop later tells the moving rectangles to move.  The boundaries are all rectangles of different dimensions, but the working ones are covering the entire left side of the screen and the entire top side of the screen.

Comment: Why do you believe that you are checking some objects twice? If you check the same object for collision twice then you are also reversing their velocities twice which is the same as not changing them at all! That might be the bug.

Comment: Checking it again I don't really know why I thought that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming _f, _b, farr, and barr do not change during the execution of the loop, your loop checks all combinations exactly once. So how is it that you "check some collisions twice"? Does setD() do something sneaky? Do you mean that once a rectangle collides there is no need to check more boundaries? If so, that can be fixed with a simple break statement. Otherwise, there likely is a problem with your inter() method, independent as to whether or not it appears to work elsewhere. Can you post your inter implementation?

There is a possibility of another problem, that of assuming continuous properties in a discrete space. As my amazing ascii art (titled: ball and wall) skills demonstrate...

Frame 1:

`o__|_`

Frame 2:

`_o_|_`

Frame 3:

`__o|_`

Frame 4:

`___|o`

Notice that the ball passed through the wall! In no frame did the ball intersect the wall. This happens if your distance moved per frame can be roughly the same or larger than the characteristic size of your moving object. This is difficult to check for with a simple intersection check. You actually need to check the path that the ball occupied between frames.

If your rectangles and barriers are oriented without rotation, this is still a fairly easy check. Use the bounding rectangle of the moving rectangle between the two frames and intersect that with the barriers.

Other ideas:

1. You are *double* colliding, switching the direction twice.
2. Your rectangles are in two different coordinate spaces.
3. Some other thread is screwing with your rects.

But basically, your code looks good. How many rectangles do you have? Can you make them distinct colors? Then, in your loop, when you collide, call setD and output the color of the rectangle that collided, and where it was. Then, when you notice a problem, kill the code and look at the output. If you see two collisions in a row (causing the rect to switch directions twice), you'll have caught your bug. Outputting the coordinates might also help, on the off chance that you are in two different coordinate spaces.

If it's a threading issue, then it's time to brush up on critical sections.

Found your mistake:

```
public void setD(){
    if(_d==0)
        _d=2;
    if(_d==1)
        _d=3;
    if(_d==2)
        _d=0;
    if(_d==3)
        _d=1;
    }
```

Each of these needs to be else if, otherwise you update 0 to become 2 and *then* 2 to become 0 in the same call.

Comment: The setD() method just changes the direction the rectangle is moving.  Also the rectangles are moving very slowly and I see them inside the boundary for multiple iterations.  I also believe that at first I check rectangle1 if it collides with boundary1, and later check if boundary1 collides with rectangle1

Comment: @Brian: if farr is the rectangles and barr is the barriers, then you only check the collision once, when n=1 and m=1. That happens once in the life of the outer loop. If you also had a `barr[n].inter(farr[m])` check, then you would be double-checking. However, depending on your implementation of `inter()`, you may *need* to do this check. This is why I asked if you would post the code.

Comment: I added the inter() method to the original post, it just allows me to use the intersects() method in a class that isn't a rectangle

Comment: I assume that rec is a member field of type Rect? Not your problem, but tip: shorten method body to `return Rect.intersects(rect, rec);` I will examine this more closely in a bit.

Comment: it seems that it only works when the rectangle is approaching the boundaries from below or from the right =/ I'm so lost, the error is probably somewhere else in the code.

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to extend Rect for some reason so the class creates a Rect and has similar parameters.

Comment: Yeah. Stupid final classes. Sucks if you want to add validation to a String too.

Comment: All right. Updated my answer. I'm fresh out of ideas. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: yeah I am going to check all those out, especially double colliding and them being in two coordinate spaces.  I feel like it is one of those.  Thanks for spending so much time on it :)

Comment: @Brian: Noooo! Obvious mistake. Can't believe I missed it. Time for us both to feel silly. See update.

Comment: FYI, I am not editing my answer to remove my beautiful ascii art, even if it wasn't at all related to your problem.

Comment: Bah! The simplest things always get me >.< thanks for catching that, works like a charm now! =D

It wouldn't be the same without the ascii art hehe